# Blackberry - HttpConnection using EDGE net

Tags: blackberry, httpconnection, cellular-network

I want to do an httpconnection for a blackberry application. Im using url like

`http://ip:port/prueba.php;deviceside=true`

If i want to use it into the device by wifi, i add interface=wifi.

But i dont know why it doesn't connect via EDGE. is there anything else i can do? I hear about something that you have sign your application but i dont understand that.

Answer (score 0):

Use : ";deviceside=true;ConnectionUID="+ srTCP.getUid()

```
 private ServiceRecord srTCP;
 private void init() 
    {

        ServiceBook sb = ServiceBook.getSB();
        ServiceRecord[] records = sb.getRecords();

        for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++)
        {
            ServiceRecord myRecord = records[i];
            String cid, uid;

            if (myRecord.isValid() && !myRecord.isDisabled()) 
            {
                cid = myRecord.getCid().toLowerCase();
                uid = myRecord.getUid().toLowerCase();
                if (cid.indexOf(WPTCP_STR) != -1 && uid.indexOf(WIFI_STR) == -1 && uid.indexOf(MMS_STR) == -1) 
                {
                    String httpProxyAddress = getDataString(myRecord, BYTE_PROXY_ADDRESS);
                    if ((httpProxyAddress == null) || StringUtils.isBlank(httpProxyAddress.trim())) 
                    {
                        srTCP = myRecord;
                    } 
                }
            }
      }
  }
```